# What does 'at the end of the week' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

(In letter about work)

Thank you for agreeing to meet with me on Friday to discuss ~~...
...(omit)..
I look forward to seeing you **at the end of the ㅡㅡ**

The answer of the blank is 'week' because the end of the week contains friday... That's what answer says. but Doesn't 'the end of the week' mean 'Saturday and Sunday'???

I'm very confused because 'the end of the week' is translated into '주말' in korean and it means usually 'Saturday and Sunday'.

Please let me know what does 'at the end of the week' mean to a extent?
thank you in advance!

Comment: If it's a meeting to discuss work, the work-week usually ends on Friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is key. In the context you give "week" means "working week" and so the "end of the week" would be on Friday.

"The end of the week" does not always mean the same as "the weekend". And in a working context the last day of the (working week) is Friday. The language is imprecise and in a different context "the end of the week" could mean Saturday or even Sunday.

Comment: And for many companies, especially during discounts, weekend usually lasts from Thursday to Tuesday.

Comment: I don't recognise that. The "weekend" means Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: That was a joke pointing out that many companies hold "weekend" sale periods that definitely last for more than two days. At least I have seen some.

Answer (score 1):

Typically:

Week = Mon-Fri

Weekend = Sat & Sun

Comment: So the end of the week (i.e. week-end) is Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: @IllidanS4 Yes but in standard cases Friday is the last day of a "work week" therefore Friday is the end of the working week. if it were Saturday or Sunday it would most likely be said, "I look forward to seeing you this weekend." I hope it is making sense.